# Creating a fixed TitledBorder around a JPanel?

Tags: java, border, titled-border

I'm using the following to create a border around a JPanel:

> setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(title));

But the border that this creates is always the same as the size of the JFrame that I add the JPanel to. It even changes when I resize it, is there any way to make this border static?

This seems like it should be an easy fix but I can't figure out how to do it, when I put

> setSize(x,y);

in my JPanel class, the border that createTitledBorder creates is still to the edges of the JFrame that I add my JPanel class to.

It shouldn't be this hard to create a fixed border, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, are you setting the border to the JPanel object?

```
JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
myPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(title));
```

If you're just saying setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(titled)); It may be adding the border to the JFrame.  You'll need to set the border on the JPanel object.